# React "Maximum update depth exceeded."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I have a container which is a child container. This child container handles `states` and it also receives some `props` from the parent. I have two select statements which `onChange` sets `state` in the child container. For some reason, the `setState()` is causing the container to re render. The weird part is that the `render()` and also my `setState()` code is called only once. (I added debugger to check). Please find my Select combobox code below:

```
                <Select
                    native
                    name="evidenceNode"
                    value={nodeType}
                    onChange={this.handleChange('nodeType')}
                    className={classes.textField}
                >
                    <option />
                    {NODE_TYPE.map(function (item, i) {
                        return <option key={i} value={item}>{item}</option>
                    })}
                </Select>

                <Select
                    native
                    name="modelType"
                    value={modelType}
                    onChange={this.handleChange('modelType')}
                    className={classes.textField}
                >
                    <option />
                    {MODEL_TYPE.map(function (item, i) {
                        return <option key={i} value={item}>{item}</option>
                    })}
                </Select>
```

Here is my handleChange function:

```
handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({
        [name]: event.target.value,
    });
};
```

I am suspecting that this is a very small fix but I don't know where am I going wrong.

Things I have tried:

1. Change the way I am calling handle change to a arrow function and it didnt work
2. I removed one of the Select statement and tried running again and it worked.
3. I tried to remove the `handleChange` call from one of the Select statement and it worked fine.

Also I should mention: I have a `componentWillReceiveProps` function (Not sure if it matters)

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext) {
    if(nextProps.selectedNode !== this.state.selectedNode){
        this.setState({
            selectedNode: nextProps.selectedNode
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you're trying to do while showing both the child and parent container?

Comment: As @davmich pointed out, need more context, especially how `componentWillReceiveProps` affects (as I think this could be what's causing the issue)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `onChange={this.handleChange('modelType')}`.

You're not attaching an event, you're calling a method with that.

You're entering in an infinite loop because of that. 
`this.handleChange('modelType')` occurs a re-render which call again `this.handleChange('modelType')`...etc

Attach on the `onChange` event an anonymous function which call `handleChange`

`onChange={e => this.handleChange('modelType', e)}`

And change `handleChange` params declaration :

`handleChange = (name, event) => {}`

Comment: almost, still need to pass event

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I had already tried to use the arrow function (just like you had suggested) for the handleChange and it didn't help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with the handleChange listener. Apparently [Material-UI]https://material-ui.com/ (The tool I am using for the form elements) required us to add a FormControl element above every Select I add. So the component should look something like this.

```
<FormControl
                // className={classes.formControl}
            >
                <Select
                    native
                    name="nodeType"
                    value={nodeType}
                    onChange={this.handleChange('nodeType')}
                    className={classes.textField}
                    inputProps={{
                        name: 'nodeType',
                        id: 'nodeType'
                    }}
                >
                    <option/>
                    {NODE_TYPE.map(function (item, i) {
                        return <option key={i} value={item}>{item}</option>
                    })}
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
```

The mistake I made was I had one FormControl and it had two Select elements inside it. This particular thing isn't documented properly on their website.

I think Material-UI recursively calls handleChange on every Select component inside the Form control and since I had more than one, it was going into a loop. I hope this helps.